# How to find the classloader of my webapp with Yourkit?

Tags: memory-leaks, weblogic, classloader, yourkit

I am working on a webapp that is deployed in Weblogic. After a few re-deployments PermGen ran out of space so I had to conclude that the webapp has a class loader leak...

I am using Yourkit to investigate that leak, but find myself stuck as I don't even know which class loader is leaking: when I do a memory dump and open it, Yourkit shows me dozens (more exactly: 289) of class loader instances. From the name I can guess that some of them are not the ones, but that still leaves many possibilities.

I tried to compare the list of class loaders before / after using the application (is it a valid approach?), but it does not help because most class loaders are instances of the same couple of classes, so I don't know which instance is the one I am interested in.

The class loaders classes reported by Yourkit are:

1. sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader
2. weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader
3. weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader
4. java.net.URLClassLoader sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader
5. weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspClassLoader
6. weblogic.diagnostics.query.QueryCompiler
7. sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader
8. javax.management.remote.rmi.NoCallStackClassLoader

If you know already which of these is used by Weblogic to load the classes of a webapp, that would already help as I did not find it in Weblogic documentation.
And can anyone suggest a methodology to find the particular class loader instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resorted to look at the list of loaded classes for each instance of `GenericClassLoader` and `ChangeAwareClassLoader` (as they seemed to be the likeliest ones) and checked if they had my own classes (filtering on package).
The webapp class loader is an instance of `ChangeAwareClassLoader`.